# Does Verizon Fios Prohibit Port Forwarding for Third-Party Routers?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, isp

*[NOTE: This post has been completely rewritten from its original form to more directly reflect what the question is.]*

Hello,

My ISP is Verizon Fios however I use my own router instead of the one that they try to provide to customers for a monthly lease.  I have had some difficuly setting up port forwarding.  Does Verizon artificially prohibit port forwarding for third-party routers?

Annecdotally, I have observed Verizon downgrading service for third-party routers, so I have reason to believe it may be possible that Verizon may also artificially prohibit other router functions.  This would not be surprising considering this ISP's documented dubious operating procedures, such as the use of super cookies, etc.

Comment: I am using a pfsense router.  I played around a little bit more with the NAT settings and got a little bit closer to my desired configuration, so that demonstrates enough for me it's not a Verizon imposition.  Such a shame that Verizon has so little credibility that I even need to second guess them when trying to trouble shoot my own network ... :sigh:

Comment: I don't see a need for the down votes.  It is a valid question  --  I mean, is there some reason you think I should give Verizon or any ISPs the benefit of the doubt?

Comment: The downvotes probably have more to do with the lack of details & info on what's been tried … or maybe just towards "Have you called Verizon tech support to ask?" or "Have you checked the router documentation?"  And why isn't the router model in the question?

Comment: But my question was about the Verizon network, not my router.  I don't want to list the make and model of my router or the version of the software because that information is kindof private.  My question was about if Verizon interferes with port forwarding, not how to configure my router to do port forwarding.  Whate router I am using is irrelevant to that question.

Comment: And yes, I have called Verizon tech support.  That was an excersize in futility because all they do is recite talking points given by managment.  I wouldn't expect a Verizon rep to say anything negative about Verizon while on the clock, I'm sure they would be fired.

Comment: Blindly trusting a corporation with a questionable track record in ethics is down right nonsense.  If you are loyal to Verizon then that's great. I admire that.  But don't impose your baseless beliefs on others and then throw around the word "conspiracy" to discredit people who express doubts about Verizon's network operations.  Trust is earned, not assumed.

Comment: I didn't assume Verizon was at fault with zero evidence.  However, considering I had zero evidence, I didn't rule out the possibility.  And in case you didn't notice, my question was not an accusation, and my answer absolved them.  You can tone up the aggression in your responses, sure, it just demonstrates your ignorance.  You can't even defend Verizon without calling me a conspiracy theorist and using the tin foil hat cliche.  Grow up.  Not everyone can be as trusting of strangers as you can.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do port forwarding on Verizon using a third-party router.  This has been confirmed with a custom router running pfsense operating system.  Port forwarding was successfully configured on that router, demonstrating that Verizon does not prohibit third-party routers from carrying out port forwarding.

However this does not imply that Verizon doesn't artificially limit third-party routers from carrying out other routine router functions.  Other router features would need to be independtly verified for Verizon interference.

Comment: This is a pretty useless answer as you don't specify which router you confirmed it with.

Comment: I disagree.  The concept of "port forwarding" is pretty universal and agnostic to specific router models.  My question is about the Verizon network, not my router.  I was having doubts about my ISP, not my router.  That is what prompted this question.  the question is not "How do I set up port forwarding on pfsense" it is "How to Port Forward with Verizon Fios" and the body of my question makes clear that I simply want to know if Verizon prohibits third-party routers from performing port forwarding or not.  This answer resolves that doubt.

Comment: Your criticism is valid.  I have rewritted the question to make it more clear what it is I am asking.

Comment: My question was about the Verizon network, not pfsense.  And the question is answered.  Conspiracy?  Who said that?  I don't trust Verizon, that's great if you do.  Why should I trust Verizon?  They haven't done anything to earn that credibility in my eyes.